# Mysql:Add conditions in group by

Tags: mysql

By using **group by source clause in query**,I am getting following result.

```
Source  No_of_users
  1         2
  2         7
  3         3
  4         34
  5         21
```

How can I group some values of source i.e output like:

```
Source   No_of_users
  1+2         9
  3+5         24
  4           34
```

Need Suggestions.

Comment: What are the criteria for this 'grouping'?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with union like:

```
SELECT SUM(no_of_users) AS some_sum from some_table where source in (1,2,3)
UNION
SELECT SUM(no_of_users) AS some_sum from some_table where source in (4,5,6)
UNION
SELECT SUM(no_of_users) AS some_sum from some_table where source in (6,7,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This......

with cte as (
    select
        case Name
            when '2' then '1'
            when '5' then '3'
              //add more combinations ....
            else Name
        end as Name
    from table
)
select Name, count(*)
from cte
group by Name
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using a nested `SELECT` to force the `Source` column to the appropriate value, then grouping the resulting rows:

```
SELECT  Source,
        SUM(No_of_users)
  FROM  (SELECT  CASE
                   WHEN Source = 1 THEN '1+2'
                   WHEN Source = 2 THEN '1+2'
                   WHEN Source = 3 THEN '3+5'
                   WHEN Source = 5 THEN '3+5'
                   ELSE Source
                 END AS Source,
                 No_of_users
         FROM  `Table`) AS A
  GROUP BY Source
```

SQL Fiddle available [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e79d8/2) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN Source in (1, 2) THEN '1+2'
             WHEN Source in (3, 5) THEN '3+5'
             ELSE Source
        END) as Source,
       SUM(No_of_users) as No_of_users
FROM  `Table` t
GROUP BY Source
ORDER BY Source;
```